# Is it possible to attach a path on docker volume in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I define a volume in `docker-compose` as follows

```
volumes:
  root_volume:
    driver: local,
    driver_opts:
        device:"/home/user/test",
        type:none
```

I need to do something like this

```
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: test_nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8015:80"
    networks:
      - test_network      
    volumes:
      - root_volume:/var/www/html
      - root_volume/dockerfiles/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - root_volume/dockerfiles/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

The first line of `volumes` directive is OK, however, the remaining 2 ones are not. Is it possible to attach path to volume?

Comment: No, you can't mount a subpath from a volume like that. You can set up an ENTRYPOINT script to copy those files from the volume into the desired destinations (but since the nginx image already has an ENTRYPOINT script you'll need to account for that).

Comment: No, you can't mount subdirectories of a named volume.  Traditional bind-mount syntax will work; better still would be to `COPY` some or all of these files into your image (maybe using a templated configuration file) and remove the `volumes:` altogether.